# What happens if a hollow eats a mod soul in candy form

Tags: bleach

My brother asked this question to me when I was watching bleach. He said, "What happens if a hollow ate a mod soul, like, when the mod soul is in its candy form, because I know one time Kon was eaten as the stuffed animal and he was spit back out, but if their in their candy form then would the mod soul be able to take over the hollow."
    I didn't know how to answer him because I didn't know myself so, I have to ask What exactly happens when a hollow eats a mod soul in candy form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We don't know.**

During the run of *Bleach*, in both manga and anime form, the matter of a mod soul being devoured by a Hollow has (surprisingly) never come up in practical discussion.

What we do know of mod souls is that they were [manufactured to help combat the Hollow](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Kaiz%C5%8D_Konpaku) since they outnumbered the Soul Reapers, but that's...about it.  It also doesn't help matters that the operation which brought them into being was shut down, and all of the mod souls were ordered to be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

first of all. mod konpaku are substitude souls. meaning the human or creature's mind has been changed and/or replaced. 
second of all hollows are old souls that have died and became monsters. 
nemu is a soul made from a mod soul and a gigai. a temporary soul. meaning she is half the subject we are talking about. 
nemu is normal. but hollows aren't.
nemu is nice. but hollows aren't.
combine the facts. probably there would be a mod soul mind with a hollow's body. that is all i can say.

Answer (score 0):

in the little side panels of some book in bleach ( I can't remember which) Hannatoro eats a soul candy and Kon starts controlling her body. I would assume what happened was that Their soul would still be in their body, but the mod soul could control the hollow